# How can I remove duplicate Objects from array of Objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array containing point objects with structure { 'x' : x , 'y' : y } .
How can I remove duplicate points from this array. I searched but didn't find solution which will work in this case. 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: How do you define "duplicate points"?

Comment: @ambarox Wrong language?

Comment: can you give/show the exact array structure with duplicates?

Comment: Got the solution !!! Duplicate point means point having same x and y co-ordinates. Thanks anyways !!!